# Is it possible to install two mail plugins together in a single Wordpress site? How to do it?

Tags: plugins, subscription, newsletter, mailing-list

I am working for a site currently having MailPoet to send all the newsletters. We have around 800 subscribers and everything is configured properly and working fine.

Now, we got around 5000 emails for a new mailing list required only for a specific event that we are hosting. Mails need to be sent to these lists just once or twice. We do not want to upgrade Mail Poet for more subscribers. Instead, I found a new newsletter SendinBlue where I can send unlimited subscribers mails.

I do not wish to disturb the current newsletters through MailPoet but install SendinBlue side by side and send the new newsletters for one time use. Is it safe to activate SendinBlue along with Mail Poet and not hamper the mail plugin?

If not, how do I ensure to not mess up? Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install our WordPress plugin to synchronise your WordPress subscribers with your SendinBlue account and send newsletters. To do so, we invite you to refer to our step by step [guide](https://help.sendinblue.com/hc/en-us/articles/208849249-Installing-the-WordPress-plugin).

In addition, installing SendinBlue plugin for WordPress should not interfere with your current MailPoet plugin. We just ran a test with both SendinBlue plugin (Version 2.6.8) and MailPoet plugin (Version 2.7.5) activated and our plugin sent a newsletter smoothly.

Should you have more questions, please do not hesitate to send an email to contact(at)sendinblue(dot)com.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't really be a problem. Just two plugins using the same function, but not actually simultaneously(even if they are both installed and activated at the same time).

You could always disable the Mail Poet plugin for the short time you have SendinBlue activated, but again: I don't see any technical reason for them to hamper each other's functions.

That said, it's always a good idea to do a backup of both the database and the files if you think what you're doing might cause hard to repair damage. I don't think this is such a case, but you should always be on the safe side of things. :)